# How could I order SOAP request headers?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, dependency-injection, .net-core

When I inject my service, I add a CustomEndpointBehavior to add a MessageInspector to add the headers that I need to succeedd the request.

The thing is that the WCF service that I'm calling is expecting at the FIRST header one specific header, that the .NET default XML serializator, serialized at the SECOND header because of his name (I think this is the issue)

```
    {
        private Configuration Configuration;

        public MessageInspector(Configuration Configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = Configuration;
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) { }
        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            var header1 = new Header1(Configuration);
            var header2 = new Header2(Configuration);

            request.Add(header1);
            request.Add(header2);

            return;
        }
    }
```

How could I set the order of the headers? And if it's a thing of the serializator how could I customize the order of serialization?

Comment: You shouldn't ever expect any sort of order in parameters sent, especially not for request headers. They are usually read in a disorderly manner, where a dictionary (or anonymous object) is assigned key/values, and the parameters are evaluated in any order. AFAIK, there is no way to specify the order of header params without making your own requests with a HttpClient or something more low-level (closer to the metal).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the first soap header is always the `Action` header, which indicates the name of the operation contract to be called. Subsequent custom message headers will be sorted according to the order we add custom message headers.

```
var header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("header1", "", "header1value");
            var header2 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("header2", "", "header2value");
            request.Headers.Add(header2);
            request.Headers.Add(header1);
```

Result.
[image]
Thereby, I am afraid it is unfeasible to sort these soap message headers before the Action Message header.
Besides, the members of the Data contract are capable of sorting in a fixed order by using “Order” property.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: The thing I think it is when injecting the Service which I have setted a custom end point behavior to order the headers, but when calling at service layer this service, the headers are not ordered as I have ordered, I think is thing about how serializes when injecting the service in .NET core